# Programmatically install a chrome extension

Tags: python, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webdriver

I'm trying to install a chrome extension which is available in the Chrome Web Store on a specific chrome profile.

I was trying to do that with Python and Selenium (with the add_extension function) it works, but in reality it only loads it during the program. Indeed, when I click on the google shortcut after the program is finished, the extension is not installed.

I already had a look on the internet (with Chrome API), but there was no answer which fits my issue.

Thanks !

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/external_extensions

Comment: This doesn't work for a specific chrome profile

Comment: Yep, there's no way for that.